# Cannot Add Principal To Named Credential

Tags: security, namedcredentials, principal

I am trying to create a named credential with a principal using the instructions at this URL - [Using API Keys with Named Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_custom_headers_and_api_keys.htm&type=5)

But, in the "Store an API Key as an Authentication Parameter in a Principal" section at step 2 it says the following - "On the external credential’s page, scroll to Principals."

but I don't have a Principal section on either the main external credentials page or the selected credential page. Am I doing something wrong? Something I don't understand? Is there a setting I need?

How do I give the user/pass for the principal?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your org is on the previous release. "Permission set mappings" was updated and renamed to "Principals" in Summer'23 release.

If you see this screenshot, "Permission Set Mapping" has the same fields that are mentioned for Principals from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_custom_headers_and_api_keys.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20principal%2C%20click%20New%2C%20and%20set%20these%20fields).
[image]

Comment: thanks Swetha, that makes sense. I am not on Summer 23' yet and didn't realize it was part of that release.